# VPN: Script at /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/ not autoexecuting on PPTP connection established

Tags: networking, vpn, ppp, pptp

My **PPTP client** is Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.2LTS.
My **PPTP Server** is a Buffalo DD-WRT Firmware.

If I establish my PPTP **VPN connection** (named Themiscyra):

```
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo pon Themiscyra
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 98:4b:e1:c7:b8:4c
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.2  Difus.:192.168.11.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::9a4b:e1ff:fec7:b84c/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:6091 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:4648 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:512969 (512.9 KB)  TX bytes:449801 (449.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:139 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:139 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
          Bytes RX:10137 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:10137 (10.1 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Protocolo punto a punto
          Direc. inet:192.168.210.154  P-t-P:192.168.210.1  Másc:255.255.255.255
          ACTIVO PUNTO A PUNTO FUNCIONANDO NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:6 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:6 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:3
          Bytes RX:72 (72.0 B)  TX bytes:78 (78.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW ec:55:f9:35:8a:98
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

... the PPTP connection gets **stablished** as `ppp0`. There are no more PPTP connections defined:

```
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo ls /etc/ppp/peers/ -la
total 16
drwxr-s--- 2 root dip  4096 jun  8 21:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 mar 12 22:37 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root dip  1093 jul 23  2014 provider
-rw-r--r-- 1 root dip   153 jun  8 21:59 Themiscyra
```

But I have prepared a simple script to **change the netmask** for ppp0 to 255.255.255.0 :

```
luis@PortatilHP:~$ ls -la /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/Themiscyra-VPN-NetMask.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96 jun  8 23:04 /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/Themiscyra-VPN-NetMask.sh
luis@PortatilHP:~$ more /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/Themiscyra-VPN-NetMask.sh
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig ppp0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

As can be seen, this script is **not autoexecuted**. So I need to start it **manually**:

```
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/Themiscyra-VPN-NetMask.sh
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 98:4b:e1:c7:b8:4c
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.2  Difus.:192.168.11.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::9a4b:e1ff:fec7:b84c/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:6398 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:4885 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:538500 (538.5 KB)  TX bytes:475909 (475.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:139 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:139 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
          Bytes RX:10137 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:10137 (10.1 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Protocolo punto a punto
          Direc. inet:192.168.210.154  P-t-P:192.168.210.1  Másc:255.255.255.0
          ACTIVO PUNTO A PUNTO FUNCIONANDO NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:6 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:6 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:3
          Bytes RX:72 (72.0 B)  TX bytes:78 (78.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW ec:55:f9:35:8a:98
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

What is going on here?

The `plog` command seems not to show any relevant info:

```
luis@PortatilHP:~$ sudo plog
Jun  8 23:12:05 PortatilHP pppd[3675]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun  8 23:12:05 PortatilHP pppd[3675]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Jun  8 23:12:05 PortatilHP pppd[3675]: local  IP address 192.168.210.154
Jun  8 23:12:05 PortatilHP pppd[3675]: remote IP address 192.168.210.1
```

... so, knowing about some **log reporting** about `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/` scripts info could be very useful for me in the future. Does such thing exists? It seems there is nothing at `/var/log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `.sh` from the script name.
You can test with:

```
run-parts --test /etc/ppp/ip-up.d
```

If it does not shows up, it is because of permission/file naming.

Comment: LOL. You were right: the `.sh` part disables the script from running. I don't know why this happens, but thanks you.